# Meaning of var $view = $().find('.something)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this javascript code inside an `Ember.View` class definition:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
    var view = this;
    var $view = this.$().find('.xxx');
    Ember.run.later($view, function(){
        $view.css(...);
    }, 100);
},
```

I don't understand the `$view = <some jQuery method result>` syntax. I've googled to see if `$view` is a valid syntax for a variable and if it means anything special. From what I can tell, `var $view` is just declaring a regular javascript variable. The `$` is a valid identifier character. So, saying `var $view` is no different from saying `var view`.

PS: The `this.$()` inside of Ember view gives us the jQuery object for the corresponding ember view object.

Comment: yes `$` is a valid character in variable name... and it can be used as the first character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a valid syntax

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables)

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).

So yes it is same as saying `var view = this.$().find('.xxx');`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people use $ in front of variables that are functions. And don't use $ when the variable is just equal to a string or number. Helps the readability of their code.

Comment: I think this is a good point. Although, in my case $ is being used to indicate, perhaps, that we're dealing with a jQuery object inside of an ember view.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's a valid character in a variable name, how else would `$` (for example, in jQuery) work?

[What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode
>   categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”,
>   “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”,
>   or “Letter number (Nl)”.